# How can I copy `.git` directory to the container with GitHub actions?

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I have a GitHub actions CI which builds a my app in the last version of this app `.git` directory is mandatory for  building it the problem is that GitHub action don't remove it in the docker build step of the CI.

Here is my CI template:

```yaml
on:
  push:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/3.3.5-MV'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      -
        name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      -
        name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      -
        name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          file: ./Dockerfile
          tags: foo/bar:latest
          push: true
      -
        name: Image digest
        run: echo ${{ steps.docker_build.outputs.digest }}
```

The Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:focal
ENV TZ=Europe/Paris
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y [all my dependencies]

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/build

#default path on docker image /usr/local
RUN cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/ -DTOOLS=0 

RUN make -j $(nproc) install

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Your `Dockerfile` controls what gets installed in your image. What does your `Dockerfile` look like?

Comment: @larsks I added the `Dockerfile` but as it works by the past and it works locally. But in the last version of the app, `.git` has became mandatory to be able to build. I checked the previously image created by GitHub action and the `git` repository is removed automatically by GitHub action. I think `uses: actions/checkout@v2` copy everything except that to minimise the weight of the image.

Comment: @larsks here is the error `#12 1.009 fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in the [docker/build-push-action@v2 action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action), which by default ignores the checkout created using the `actions/checkout@v2` action:

> By default, this action uses the Git context so you don't need to use the actions/checkout action to check out the repository because this will be done directly by BuildKit.
>
> The git reference will be based on the event that triggered your workflow and will result in the following context: `https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>.git#<ref>`.

When you pass a `git` build context to `docker build`, it won't
include the `.git` directory.

If you read through the documentation for the `docker/build-push-action@v2` action, you'll see that you can override this behavior:

> However, you can use the Path context using the context input alongside the actions/checkout action to remove this restriction.

You would need to modify your workflow so that it includes an explicit
`context: .`, like this:

```
        name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          tags: foo/bar:latest
          push: true
```

I've put together an example repository that demonstrates this [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-71157844); you can see the verification in [this build run](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-71157844/runs/5233312650?check_suite_focus=true).

Comment: Thank you ! It works like a charm. The purpose of the `context` wasn't very clear to me have a good day !